# How can I design and set the height of UICollectionView and prevent it for collapsing?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm beginner on iOS Swift, trying to make an horizontal scroll collection view (like Android's recycler view). I have searched many times here and google, and tried different tutorials for making it.

I'm not familiar with xCode storyboard and the process of designing the interface, constrains, etc, so I don't know how to set the height for my CollectionView and prevent it for collapsing.

I upload two screenshots, one of the storyboard, and the other of the simulator.

Thanks for any advice.

[image: Storyboard view]

[image: Simulator view]

Comment: put a minimum height constraint to your collection view `>= 50` for example where minimum height will be 50

Comment: Thanks, will try (this sound obvious, but I repeat that I'm new on xcode storyboards... Haha)

Comment: its ok, nobody's born knowing ;)

Comment: Added as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put a minimum height constraint to your collection view `>= 50` for example where minimum height will be 50, and that should fix your issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize { 
      return CGSize(width:wid, height:hei) 
  }
```

With

```
class VC :  UICollectionViewDelegate  , UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout { }
```

Comment: Thanks!! This also solves my runtime warning about FlowLayout.